# use LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, task, .net-core

As all know, we can use `LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler` at .net Framework 4.x.
[Official LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler.cs](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Execution-Time-Based-dd4dbdb6/sourcecode?fileId=67470&pathId=1378361369)

It is an implementation for `.net core`?

Comment: It's not **official**, it's a sample implementation. Did you try to port the code?

Comment: I have changed the code to .net core. generic test passed. https://gist.github.com/Aimeast/15c838d261d84e325063d4f0a1a9c494